# Akamai error: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: cdn

We use Akamai as a CDN and recently started getting an error in chrome

ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us it's happened whenever our SSL certs were invalid in some way:

- When the cert on our origin server had expired
- When we had 2 different SSL domains being served from one origin server, and didn't have "Enable SNI" turned on in the Akamai configuration.